# Spring Batch CommandLineJobRunner with parameters

Tags: spring-batch

I'm working on a simple batch : one job, one step, one reader ,one processor ,one writer

Currently, i'm running it using the CommandLineJobRunner specifying the configuration class and the name of the job :

CommandLineJobRunner MyConfigurationClass myJobName

Is it possible to add parameters at the end of the line and then use these parameters on my writer ? If it is how can i do it? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok it was CommandLineJobRunner myConfigurationClass myJob parameterName=parametervalue

then i can catch this paramater in the java code with
@Value({jobParameters['parameterName']})